# how to query on the user in the marketing cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect

I want to know which user belongs to which Business Unit and what role they are assigned to?

Can we query the the user in marketing cloud to get this information.

I am getting confused for which user is assigned to which business unit and roles.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Is this a developer type question? I'm just trying to understand what "query" means. You can get much of what sounds like what you're looking for by API. There's no Data View to use SQL on, but you can get much of the data back into data extensions to "query" from there.

Answer (score 2):

You do not query to find out the users information in marketing cloud to see what business unit or role they are assigned to.

You can simply check from the user interface level by navigating to the following:

**Email Studio > Email > Admin > My Users**

You will see a drop down pane which will contain My Users, Business Units, Roles which can be viewed or managed.

[image]

You can then select a user in "**My Users**" and choose to view the following information by selecting "**Manage Roles**" or "**Manage Business Units**" for that user you have selected.

[image]

Hope this helps.